# Cannot Setup DFS namespace on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have an EC2 instance which I have domain joined using the AWS microsoft Active Directory.  I installed the DFS namespace and DFS replication roles in server management.

But now when I go to Add new namespace I get an error saying: 
"Cannot connect to the  domain"
[image]

When I try to do Delegate Management permissions I get a similar kind of error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was my bad, I was RDP'ed into the instance and not domain joined with it.